# how to show absent and present using mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

how to show absent and present
this code is showing only present but i want absent result also with date
if i remove  `WHERE a.date BETWEEN '2015-05-20' AND '2015-05-20'`

this then absent and present result is showing perfect but i want with selected date

how to fix this issue please help me to fix this issue

thanks

live example please se this link

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9604f/2

Mysql code

```
SELECT s.user_name, s.user_pass,a.date
    ,  CASE WHEN a.user_name IS NOT NULL THEN 'Present' ELSE 'Absent' END as attendance_status
    FROM users s 
    LEFT JOIN attend a on s.user_name=a.user_name WHERE a.date BETWEEN '2015-05-20' AND '2015-05-20'
```

Comment: What should the desired result look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the condition from the `where` to the `on` clause:

```
SELECT s.user_name, s.user_pass, a.date,
       (CASE WHEN a.user_name IS NOT NULL THEN 'Present' ELSE 'Absent'
        END) as attendance_status
FROM users s LEFT JOIN
     attend a
     ON s.user_name = a.user_name AND a.date BETWEEN '2015-05-20' AND '2015-05-20';
```

The `WHERE` clause turns the outer join into an inner join, because it filters out the `NULL` values.